# Redirecting the default page after login into Alfresco (non-Admin!)

Tags: authentication, alfresco

I want the user to get to the user-sites page after his login. I understood that I have to change the code in the site-index.jsp like:

```
FROM: response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + userHomePage);
TO: response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/page/user/" + userid + "/user-sites");
```

My problem right now is that I don't want the Admin to land on this page! So I tried something like:

```
if (!user.isAdmin){
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/page/user/" + userid + "/user-sites");
  }
  else{
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + userHomePage);
  }
```

But without success. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for identifying whether the user is admin or not, in site-index.jsp.

```
FrameworkUtil.getServiceRegistry().getAuthorityService().isAdminAuthority("userName")
```

===========================================================================

Below might seems to be a bad way but I don't think there will be another option.

```
Connector conn = FrameworkUtil.getConnector(context,"alfresco");
ConnectorContext c = new ConnectorContext(HttpMethod.GET);
c.setContentType("application/json");
Response res = conn.call("/api/people/"+userid);
System.out.print(res);
```

With above code you can get details of user.If you check in response you will get one field called *isAdmin* inside *capabilities*.You can evaluate using that.

You have to import below things in page as well.

```
<%@ page import="org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.connector.Connector"%>
<%@ page import="org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.connector.ConnectorContext"%>
<%@ page import="org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.connector.HttpMethod"%>
<%@ page import="org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.connector.Response"%>
```

Comment: Hmm... it still doesn't work. I changed my code now to: `if (!FrameworkUtil.getServiceRegistry().getAuthorityService().isAdminAuthority(userid)){
 response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/page/user/" + userid + "/user-sites");
      }` What did i wrong? I even tried with "userid.user". And how did you know that? Whats your source for such problems?